# проблема с обновлением pip install

Tags: python, pip

[image]

Почему ошибка? Можете подсказать другой вариант апгрейда пип?

Comment: Набрать `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` в системной командной строке, а не в python-интерпретаторе, очевидно

Comment: Спасибо! Блин, ну почему я такой глупый(

Answer (score 1):

win+r, cmd, pip install --upgrade pip, enter

Comment: Все гениальное просто)

Comment: @АндрейКарев хахаха, ну да, сработало?

Comment: да, сработало!)